# php contact form drops "Name" field

Tags: php, email

I have a contact form with a "Name" field:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="contactengine.php" id="commentForm" style="display:table; margin:20px auto">

 <div class="well">

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="sr-only" for="Email">Email address</label>
 <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter email address" autofocus>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="sr-only" for="Name">Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Last, First" >
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="sr-only" for="Rating">Rating</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="rating" type="number" name = "Rating" id = "Rating" min="1200" max="2500" value="2000">
 </div> 

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="sr-only" for="City">Location</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="City, Country" name="City" id="City" pattern=".{2,23}" />
 </div> 

 </div>

<div class="well">
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">

<textarea placeholder = "Optionally, list some chess background info here about your abilities and style. Include experience, books read, goals, strengths and weaknesses, even a pgn file." name="Message" id="Message" rows="4" class="required" style="width:100%"></textarea>

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

<div style="margin: 0 auto; display:table;">

<button type="reset" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning bold" style="float:left; font-size:18px; margin:20px 40px">Reset</button>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success bold" style="float:right; font-size:18px; margin:20px 40px">Submit</button>

</div>
</div>

</form>
```

and I have a php script to handle it:

```
<?php

// CHANGE THE VARIABLES BELOW


$EmailFrom = "joeblow@gmail.com";
$EmailTo = "joeblow@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Contact Form Submission";

$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Rating = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Rating'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$City = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";

$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Rating: ";
$Body .= $Rating;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Location: ";
$Body .= $City;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page
// CHANGE THE URL BELOW TO YOUR "THANK YOU" PAGE
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
?>
```

The problem is the script works, EXCEPT that it doesn't send the name, Just "Name: " and no name picked up from the form. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What shows `var_dump($_POST['Name'], $Name);`?

Comment: Place `error_reporting(-1);` as a first line of your script and see some wonderful information

Comment: Add this to the top of your PHP code: `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); echo '<pre'.print_r($_POST, TRUE).'</pre>';` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Please don't use UC first for PHP function - like trim()

Comment: works fine on mine, no problem. turn on error reporting in both files and in contactengine.php check if all the the variables are set or not. Give a try.

Comment: I did what was suggested and it returned: Notice: Undefined index: Name in /home/rmack/public_html/chessresearcher/contactengine.php on line 13

Comment: However I can't see anything wrong with line 13 (the "Name" input)

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me. You can validate the form field "Name" like this (and in many other ways too, but here is quick fix):

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']) && !empty($_POST['Name'])) {
    //your PHP code 
}
```

Comment: I got it to work by arranging the form inputs to match the php contactengine. What an ugly kludge! I think maybe I just purged non-ascii characters or something like that.